# Checking whether number is Armstrong Number or not in C

Tags: c, input, output

**Armstrong number** is a number that is equal to the sum of cubes of its digits. For example 0, 1, 153, 370, 371, and 407 are the Armstrong numbers.

I tried this program this way-

```
    // Program to check whether number is Armstrong number or not
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()


{
    int a,r,sum=0,temp;
    //accepting input from user
    printf("Enter a number to check whether it is Armstrong number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    //condition for checking if sum of individual numbers cube is equal to number
  do
  {
      r = a % 10;
      sum += r*r*r;
      a = a/10;

  } while (a>0);
  
    
    //printing final result.
    if(temp == sum)
    {printf("It is Armstrong Number.");}
    else
    {
        printf("It is not Armstrong Number.");
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Here, I always got the result that it is not Armstrong Number, so I checked the internet and they used a temp variable to store the input number. Why is that neccessary?
How does adding the temp variable amke the code work? and what are the other mistakes?
This is the code that worked:-

```
// Program to check whether number is Armstrong number or not
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,r,sum=0,temp;
    //accepting input from user
    printf("Enter a number to check whether it is Armstrong number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    temp = a;
    //condition for checking if sum of individual numbers cube is equal to number
  do
  {
      r = a % 10;
      sum += r*r*r;
      a = a/10;

  } while (a>0);
  
    
    //printing final result.
    if(temp == sum)
    {printf("It is Armstrong Number.");}
    else
    {
        printf("It is not Armstrong Number.");
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: `temp` is used without being initialized and *undefined behavior* is invoked in the first code.

Comment: `a = a/10;` changes the value stored in the variable `a`. Since you want to compare the sum of the cubes with the original number, you need to keep this number somewhere. This happens to be the variable named `temp`  in the second code snippet. Also probably you should check, if the number entered was negative...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `temp` in the conditioon `temp == sum`, but you didn't assign anything to `temp` before that. The value of `temp` here is indeteminate because it is a non-initialized non-static variable (having automatic storage duration). Using such indetrminate value invokes *undefined behavior*.

The other mistakes are inconsitent indentation and that the result of `scanf()` isn't checked. Also lack of checking to avoid overflow in the multiplication and addition can be counted as a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   int a,r,sum=0,temp;
   ```

   `temp` is not initialized in the first code.
2. > they used a temp variable to store the input number. Why is that neccessary?

**Reason :** After execution of do-while loop, the value of `a` becomes zero. So, you don't have the original number to compare with the `sum` variable. So, we make a copy of the original number `a`.